# Spinner не отображает данные в диалоговом окне android

Tags: android, arrayadapter

Я пытаюсь сделать в диалоговом окне AlertDialog выпадающий список spinner. Получаю данные из базы Firebase и добавляю их в arrayadapter. Проблема в том, что spinner ничего не показывает, если на него нажать, то появляется список данных, но при выборе spinner опять становится пустым... И эта проблема замечена мной именно в диалоговом окне.

```java
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("parts").child(firebaseUser.getPhoneNumber());
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();

                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                Part partValues = ds.getValue(Part.class);
                                parts.add(partValues.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterParts = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parts);
                adapterParts.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) acceptDialogView.findViewById(R.id.selectPartSpinner);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapterParts);

                spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: посмотрите есть ли данные в спиннере под отладкой, возможно из базы ничего не вытаскивается по итогу

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение. Я пытался загружать данные из базы только тогда когда пользователь нажмет (onClick) чтобы открыть диалоговое окно, но когда я перенес запрос к базе в onCreate все заработало хорошо.